# Why I get errors when I try to display google analytics in Iframe?

Tags: javascript, angular, web, iframe, google-analytics

I use Iframe to display google analytics in my website based on angular 12.

Here is the component where iframe is used:

Typescript:

```
export class UserReportComponent implements OnInit {

   URL: string;


  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.URL= this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(path-to-google-analytics)
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="950" [src]="URL" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But when the component is opened in the console I get those errors:

```
Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute
```

Any idea how to fix the error?